# How to validate input email list using jQuery validator?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have input fields to enter email list like `test1@gmail.com`, `test2@gmail.com`, . . . , `etc@gmail.com`

I want to get those emails separated by comma. I use `jQuery validator` plugin.
How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: So their are multiple inputs fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate it by pattern matching as below code

```
<input type="email" multiple pattern="^([\w+-.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4},*[\W]*)+$" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j1jzL8xd/

**Validation with jQuery**

**html:**

```
<form id="form" method="post">
Enter email:<input type="text" name="emails" id="emails" class="emails"><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "multiemails",
     function(value, element) {
         if (this.optional(element)) // return true on optional element
             return true;
         var emails = value.split(/[,]+/); // split element by ,
         valid = true;
         for (var i in emails) {
             value = emails[i];
             valid = valid &&
                     jQuery.validator.methods.email.call(this, $.trim(value), element);
         }
         return valid;
     },

   jQuery.validator.messages.multiemails
);

$("#form").validate({
     rules: {
                emails: { required: true, multiemails: true }
            },
     messages: {
                    emails: {
                                required: "Email required",
                                multiemails: "finish typing email and dont end with comma"
                            }
               }

});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xFphm/242/